# Store Each Line of PowerShell Output as same variable

Tags: powershell, variables, printing, invoke-command

So, I'm trying to remotely remove some manually added printer from a separate machine. Problem is, I don't want to remove all of the printers, only ones that have "HJK" **or** "LSG" anywhere in the name.

So, to get the list of names, I do:

```
Invoke-Command AaronsComputer -ScriptBlock {get-printer | select name -expandproperty name}
```

and to delete the printer, I would do:

```
Invoke-Command AaronsComputer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Printer -Name "Full Printer Name Here"}
```

I know I can export the results of get-printer as a CSV to work with it better but I'd rather not do that and have it all happen in Powershell.

I thought something along these lines would work but I don't think PowerShell intelligently sees each line as a variable.

```
$PrinterResults = Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {get-printer | select name -expandproperty name}

foreach $PrinterResults

if ($PrinterResults -contains "HJK") { 
  Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Printer -Name "$PrinterResults"}
}

if ($PrinterResults -contains "LSG") { 
  Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Printer -Name "$PrinterResults"}
}
```

The end goal is that I can delete all printers that match the criteria in one go.

Comment: You do not need double quotes : Remove-Printer -Name "$PrinterResults"  You should use foreach($PrinterResult in $PrinterResults({.....}

Comment: You can filter the list of printers with ```where-object```- e.g. ```$PrinterResults = ... | where-object { ($_ -contains "HJK") -or ($_ -contains "LSG") }``` and then just ``foreach``` over the entire ```$PrinterResults``` list...

Comment: @mclayton

So, turns out I only need to get rid of "HJK" printers. I have the below command but that doesn't appear to work either:

`$PrinterResults = Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {get-printer -Name "*HJK*" | select name -expandproperty name}

ForEach ($Printer in $PrinterResults)

{

Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {Remove-Printer -Name $Printer }

}`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this done in the end with the below:

```
Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {
$Printers = get-printer | Where-Object {($_.name -like '*HJK*') -or ($_.name -like '*LSG*')} | Select Name -expandproperty name
foreach ($PrinterName in $Printers)
{
    printui.exe /dl /n $PrinterName
}
}
```